# Find the circle equation passing through i, 1+i, 2-i in the form of |z-p| = r|z-q|

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that the circle equation becomes $|w - c/1-r^2| = |c| \frac r{1-r^2}$.

I started by assigning $i$, $1+i$, $2-i$ to the variables $z$, $p$, and $q$ respectively. I am not sure I am doing this right. Can anyone help with the steps on how to complete the question?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Get the equation of perpendicular bisectors of the lines joining $i, 1 + i$ and $i, 2 - i$, respectively. The point of the intersection of these perpendicular bisectors is the ***_*__** of the circle ...

Comment: I found that x=1/2 and y=-1/2, I do not know how to then plug this into the circle equation for a final answer.. Having trouble with assigning variables. Can you help?

Comment: So, you found the centre of the required circle to be $1/2 - i/2$. Now, calculate the radius by taking the distance of this centre from any of the three already given points. And, you know the circle!